# Create Oracle Stored Procedure with exisiting code

Tags: sql, oracle, procedure

I have the following script which i run inside oracle to return some data, however I want to store this as a stored procedure so I don't have to keep re-running this whole bit of code at run time. If anyone can let me know how to do this, I would be very grateful. I've been experimenting already but not had much luck.

Below is the code I want to run from the stored procedure.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
declare 
cursor c_emp is
select *
from train;
r_emp c_emp%ROWTYPE;
begin
open c_emp;
loop
fetch c_emp into r_emp;
exit when c_emp%NOTFOUND;
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(r_emp.trainid);
end loop;
close c_emp;
end;
```

Comment: You need the result as result set right?

Comment: Thanks all for your suggestions. Very helpful indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create or replace procedure procedure_name
is
begin
declare 
cursor c_emp is
select *
from train;
r_emp c_emp%ROWTYPE;
begin
open c_emp;
loop
fetch c_emp into r_emp;
exit when c_emp%NOTFOUND;
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(r_emp.trainid);
end loop;
close c_emp;
end;
end procedure_name;
/
```

**then just execute the procedure by :-**

```
execute procedure_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to a ref cursor, you can use a pipelined function (which is easier to use in some SQL clients):

```
create type id_list as table of integer
/

CREATE OR REPLACE function get_trains
  return id_list
  pipelined
as
begin  
  for train_rec in (select trainid from train) loop
    pipe row (train_rec.trainid);
  end loop;
  return;
end;
/
```

This can be used in the following manner:

```
select *
from table(get_trains());
```

Answer (score 0):

You need cursor to select data in oracle. Please refer the link [Oracle – Returning a recordset from a stored procedure](http://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2007/08/06/oracle-returning-a-recordset-from-a-stored-procedure/) for more details.

```
-- Create package
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE types
AS
type cursorType is ref cursor;
END;

-- Here we have declared cursor variable of type cursorType as an output variable.
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_SELECT_DATA
(
  p_ResultSet        OUT  TYPES.cursorType
)
AS
BEGIN
  OPEN p_ResultSet FOR
  select * from your_table;
END SP_SELECT_DATA;

--Testing
VARIABLE resultSet  REFCURSOR
EXEC SP_SELECT_DATA(:resultSet);
PRINT :resultSet
```